# Is $f$ measurable with respect to the completion of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A}$ on $[0, 1]^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0, 1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that for every $x \in [0, 1]$ the function $y \to f(x, y)$ is Lebesgue measurable on $[0, 1]$ and for every $y \in [0, 1]$ the function $x \to f(x, y)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$.

Is $f$ measurable with respect to the completion of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A}$ on $[0, 1]^2$?

Here $\mathcal{A}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Fubini's theorem would give you the result under which other assumptions? Can you think of $f$ in those conditions which do not satisfy the other assumptions of Fubini's theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For $n\in\Bbb N$ define 
$$
f_n(x,y)=\cases{f(k/n,y),&$(k-1)/n\le x<k/n, k=1,2,\ldots,n$\cr f(1,y),&$x=1$.\cr}
$$
The function $f_n$ is $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal A$-measurable (even $\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal A$-measurable, where $\mathcal B$ denotes the Borel subsets of $[0,1]$). Because $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, the function $f$ is $\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal A$-measurable.

This approximation argument works even if  $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is only continuous from the right on $[0,1)$. A similar approximation would work for left-continuous functions.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the great answer. I have a few questions. Why are we using the tensor product here? Why is $f_n$ $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A}$-measurable? How do I see that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$? And why does it follow from $f_n$ converging pointwise to $f$ that $f$ is $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{A}$-measurable?

Comment: The notation $\mathcal A\times\mathcal A$ is ambiguous: it is literally the Cartesian product of $\mathcal A$ with itself; namely $\{(A_1,A_2):A_i\in\mathcal A\}$.  The $\sigma$-field of interest here is $\sigma\{A_1\times A_2: A_i\in\mathcal A\}$, for which I prefer the notation $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal A$.

Comment: Can you tell why $f_{n}$ are $A \otimes A$  measurable??

Comment: $f_n(x,y) =1_{\{1\}}(x)f(1,y)+\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{((k-1)/n,k/n]}(x)f(k/n,y)$, and each term in this sum is the product of a Borel measurable function of $x$ and a Lebesgue measurale function of $y$. As the Borel $\sigma$-field is contained in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-field, each  term is $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal A$-measurablehence so is $f_n$.