# $f$ measurable with respect to completion of product $\sigma$-algebra on $[0, 1]^2$, followup.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I asked the following question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1959868/is-f-measurable-with-respect-to-the-completion-of-the-product-sigma-algebra).

> Let $f: [0, 1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that for every $x \in [0, 1]$ the function $y \to f(x, y)$ is Lebesgue measurable on $[0, 1]$ and for every $y \in [0, 1]$ the function $x \to f(x, y)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$.
>
> Is $f$ measurable with respect to the completion of the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A}$ on $[0, 1]^2$?
>
> Here $\mathcal{A}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $[0, 1]$.

[John Dawkins](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/189130/john-dawkins) gave the following answer.

> Yes. For $n\in\Bbb N$ define 
>   $$
> f_n(x,y)=\cases{f(k/n,y),&$(k-1)/k\le x<k/n, k=1,2,\ldots,n$\cr f(1,y),&$x=1$.\cr}
> $$
>   The function $f_n$ is $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal A$-measurable (even $\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal A$-measurable, where $\mathcal B$ denotes the Borel subsets of $[0,1]$). Because $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, the function $f$ is $\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal A$-measurable.
>
> $($The notation $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A}$ is ambiguous: it is literally the Cartesian product of $\mathcal{A}$ with itself; namely $\{(A_1, A_2) : A_i \in \mathcal{A}\}$. The $\sigma$-field of interest here is $\sigma\{A_1 \times A_2 : A_i \in \mathcal{A}\}$, for which I prefer the notation $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A}$.$)$

I have a few questions.

1. How do I see that $f_n$ $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A}$-measurable?
2. How do I see that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$?
3. Why does it follow from $f_n$ converging pointwise to $f$ that $f$ is $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{A}$-measurable?

Comment: Why is a question essentially duplicating a previous one, getting upvotes? To ask for some explanations about an answer, post a comment to said answer, not a dup question. (Anyway, signaling this question to the other user seems a minimum, no?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you consider the preimage $f_n^{-1}(\{f(k/n,y)\})$ with respect to the first coordinate, you see that you get the interval $[(k-1)/n,k/n)$, which is measureable with respect to the Lebesgue measure.
2. $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous, so the endpoints of the intervalls where $f_n$ is constant converge to the same limit.